# Copy, rename and update worksheet template

Tags: excel, vba

I can copy a template and rename based on a list with the below code. But i can't figure out how i can take values from sheet 2 and update the template copies. Like In every template i want to update Cell B3 based on Lists in Sheet 2 Column B. Again In templates Cell C6 Should be updated from Values In Sheet 2 Column c. Thanks a million for your support.

```
Sub CopySheet()

Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow

    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets(i)

    ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1)

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works beautifully with me. The only change I would recommend is to specify the new name as `ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value` (specifying the `Value` property) but that is cosmetic and doesn't affect the function. Check whether the error you get might be caused by your testing procedure, not your code. Also advise which error that is - if it persists - and on which line of your code.

Comment: I don't get any error. I want to add a new function with this code. I want certain values of newly created worksheet also change based on the list. Like on every new template cell b2 will be changed according to column B in the list sheet which is sheet 2

Comment: Use... `With ActiveSheet`

Comment: I suggest you re-work your question to express what you want in as clear language as you can muster.

Comment: Are the values you want to move to each new sheet on the same row in sheet 2, that the name is e.g. `ActiveSheet.Name=Sheet2.Cells(i,1).Value` and then `ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = Sheet2.Cells(i,2).Value`, etc.

Comment: Sheet name will be taken from column A, Title will be from Column B, and another value should be from column c. Now when the templates are copied it should take the vales from row 1, then next template should take the value from row 2 and so on. the code i used only takes the sheet name from column a but i need other two values from the list and placed them inside the new copied templates.

Comment: @GMalc Your code worked. I added that with the code i used and it worked like i wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the Code from @GMalc I edited the code and tested it. It works so thought i post it here. All the credit goes to @Gmalc

```
Sub CopySheet()
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LastRow
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets(i)
    ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1)
    ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2)
    ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3)
Next i
End Sub
```